# How to extract a specific value from a dictionary?

Tags: python

I wrote a code and it gave me as output a .txt file with a thousand lines.
I would like to extract the time only. For example, for the line under, it should extract `"52 mins"`:

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
        "1000 Bd Sainte-Anne, Saint-Charles-Borrom\u00e9e, QC J6E 6J2, Canada"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "Montreal, QC H2M 1L5, Canada"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "70.2 km",
                        "value": 70233
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "52 mins",
                        "value": 3105
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

How can I do it? In my original code, I tried using `['duration'][0]['text']` :

`print(*distances['duration'][0]['text'], sep="\n")`

but it gave me this error :

```
print(*distances['duration'][0]['text'], sep="\n")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

**EDIT:**

For example, all my lines in my file are stacked one over the other like that:

```
{'destination_addresses': ['150 Av. Rouleau, Rimouski, QC G5L 5T1, Canada'], 'origin_addresses': ['Montreal, QC H2M 1L5, Canada'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '541 km', 'value': 541028}, 'duration': {'text': '5 hours 23 mins', 'value': 19405}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}

{'destination_addresses': ['150 Av. Rouleau, Rimouski, QC G5L 5T1, Canada'], 'origin_addresses': ['Montreal, QC H2M 1L5, Canada'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '541 km', 'value': 541028}, 'duration': {'text': '5 hours 23 mins', 'value': 19405}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

Comment: `'duration': {'text':`... This is a dictionary. Dictionaries do not have numbers indicies. Can you explain why you added `[0]`?

Comment: `distances['duration']` is a dict so call it in the field text: `distances['duration']['text']` should do the trick

Comment: Your outer object is a dict.  `dct['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']` should do it.

Comment: Break what you are trying to do into smaller parts to find where the error is. For example `print(distance['duration']` will show you that this is a dict, not a list. And you will see the keys you can use in that dict.

Comment: @UlisesBussi I tried it, still giving me the same error..

Comment: Sorry i rearanged your data to ease reading. now the value is in `distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'] I think that what you have is a json, maybe there's a easy way to convert it in a dictionary

Comment: please add the output of `print(distances)` to your post so we can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you did not explain the task well and you confused the users

First of all the dictionary shown above in the task is actually a string that contains your text file

In that case if you read the contents of the text file and try to get the element in the way you wrote you get an error, for example:

```
with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/readme.txt') as f:
    distances = f.readlines()

print(distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
```

> **error:**
> print(distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

1. For example you should use the **eval()** function to convert your string into dictionary. Python’s **eval()** allows you to evaluate arbitrary Python expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based input.

   ```
    with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/readme.txt') as f:
        distances = f.read()
    distances_ = eval(distances)

    print(distances_['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
   ```
2. Or you can use  **json.loads()**

   You can easily convert python string to the dictionary by using the
   inbuilt function of loads of json library of python.

   ```
    import json
    with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/readme.txt') as f:
        distances = f.read()
    distances_ = json.loads(distances)

    print(distances_['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
   ```

EDIT based on comment:

```
with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/readme.txt') as f:
    distances = f.readlines()
    for _ in distances:
        if 'distance' in _ :
           distances_ = eval(_)
           print(distances_['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
```

Comment: my .txt file is full of the same example i gave you. How do I iterate over every single one of these lines to print what I need?

Comment: @CodingN00b I wrote an edit

Comment: print(next(f).split("\"")[3])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @CodingN00b new edit

Comment: man thank you so much for your help, but i'm still getting an error : 
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @CodingN00b can you post your text file

Comment: @CodingN00b another edit

Comment: no error, but not printing anything!.. I dont know how to upload the file in my question

Comment: I edited my question to give you in example of how the lines are stack on one another @ncica

Comment: @CodingN00b I just noticed your edit, I write another edit im my post,I hope it works now

Comment: perfect.. it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your perseverance and will to help me.

Comment: Great, I am glad that I helped ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have something like:

```
data = {'destination_addresses': ['1000 Bd Sainte-Anne, Saint-Charles-Borromée, QC J6E 6J2, Canada'], 'origin_addresses': ['Montreal, QC H2M 1L5, Canada'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '70.2 km', 'value': 70233}, 'duration': {'text': '52 mins', 'value': 3105}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}
print(data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
```

Comment: it's still giving me the same exact error

Comment: @CodingN00b These two lines do exactly what you want, so your error is now elsewhere

Comment: You did not understand the task well. the example of the dictionary in the task is actually a string in his text file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confusing the dictionary structure and trying to access the array items like a dictionary.

As you said, you have a thousand lines so assuming you have multiple rows and multiple elements in each row and you want to access duration -> text for each, you can iterate over them as such and apply any conditions necessary:

```
data = {'destination_addresses': ['1000 Bd Sainte-Anne, Saint-Charles-Borromée, QC J6E 6J2, Canada'], 'origin_addresses': ['Montreal, QC H2M 1L5, Canada'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '70.2 km', 'value': 70233}, 'duration': {'text': '52 mins', 'value': 3105}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}

for row in data['rows']:
    for element in row['elements']:
         print(element['duration']['text'])
```

or in your current dictionary it can simply be printed as

```
print(data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
```

Comment: but the example in my post is simply one line out of a thousand. How do I apply your example to all the lines?!

Comment: `with open('add.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        print(i['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'])
`
I tried this, but i'm getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers"